# FastAPI websocket ping/pong timeout

Tags: websocket, fastapi, uvicorn, starlette

I am using FastAPI with `@app.websocket` to listen for incoming websockets. How does FastAPI (or Starlette or Uvicorn underneath) do ping/pong heartbeats? Is this configurable? I cannot find it in the documentation at all.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/")
def ws(websocket: WebSocket):
    pass
```

`fastapi` uses `starlette`, and under the hood it seems to use `websockets`. `websockets.connect` by default uses a `ping_interval` and `ping_timeout` of 20 seconds, but I can't tell if that is used in FastAPI.

Comment: the ping pong happens in uvicorn, and there's no current way to configure those values, there's an open issue here : https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/245 , PR welcome !

Comment: @euri10 Thanks for the pointer. I'm glad to know it uses the same 20 second defaults. I would love to do a PR, but right now I still don't understand the internals well enough to know how to pass that. I'll keep digging, thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: @euri10 Just saw https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/pull/1048. Thank you so much, that is perfect. If you want to turn this into an answer, I'll gladly accept it and give you the internet points :)

Comment: haha thanks for the reminder ! I added an answer that reflects current usage !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now use the 2 following flags:

1. `--ws-ping-interval <float>` - Set the WebSockets ping interval, in seconds. Please note that this can be used only with the default `websockets` protocol.
2. `--ws-ping-timeout <float>` - Set the WebSockets ping timeout, in seconds. Please note that this can be used only with the default `websockets` protocol.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically in the code? Somewhere in 
await websocket.accept()

Comment: @Sayanc2000  When running uvicorn, you can pass them to the `run` method, e.g. `uvicorn.run('app:app', ws_ping_interval=300, ws_ping_timeout=300)`

Comment: `uvicorn main:app --ws-ping-timeout 2.0` expected to terminate WS in 2 sec but not working for me. Its 32s