# FastAPI: WebSocket connection close after ~40s

Tags: websocket, fastapi, uvicorn, zephyr-rtos

I try to ping/pong json packages between a FastAPI websocket endpoint and a client using the websocket library from Zephyr RTOS. Unfortunately the connection is closed by the FastAPI server after ~40 seconds. This time seems to be constant. My guess is, that there must occur a timeout event due to a missing/wrong condition.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847205/fastapi-websocket-ping-pong-timeout.) seems to address my issue. Unfortunately my code is [not running with a newer uvicorn version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479225/fastapi-error-when-trying-to-open-a-websocket-connection-after-updating-uvicorn) which would support --ws-ping-interval or --ws-ping-timeout.

For a simple test I did the following:

Server side:

```
@app.websocket("/ws/update_status")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_json()
        await websocket.send_json('{"status":"ok"}')
```

Client side (C code running on Zephyr-RTOS):

```
// some code to define JSON package

while(1)
{
    websocket_send_msg(sock, send_buffer, json_length, WEBSOCKET_OPCODE_DATA_TEXT, true, true, SYS_FOREVER_MS);
    websocket_recv_msg(sock, receive_buffer, sizeof(receive_buffer), &message_type, 0, SYS_FOREVER_MS);
}
```

I use the following package versions:

```
uvicorn=='0.13.4'
fastapi=='0.68.2'
```

Does anyone know why the connection aborts after 40 seconds and how it can be avoided?

Comment: Solved it by using hypercorn instead of uvicorn. After 5 minutes the connection is still up and running.

Comment: how you  configure the hypercorn loog system in fast api when you use hypercorn ?

Answer (score 0):

uvicorn defaults the ping timeout and interval to 20 seconds each ([link](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/2c55f204bfd8464b6e22445284b57052ea022bfa/uvicorn/main.py#L479)). there is a now [a setting](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#implementation) to change these values, but from what i can tell, the ping timeout cannot be disabled in uvicorn. [here is a github issue](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/1609) that was closed without being fully resolved/addressed.